# why is my get api not working but post api can post to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api

[image]I am working on an e-commerce app using MERN, but presently i am still working on the backend, i observed that i can post to Mongodb from Postman and get a desire result, but when i tried to get (in particular) any Id i get from my post, it is not working. Here is my codes below:

"GETONE Middleware"

```
router.get('/:productId', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.productId;
    Product.findById(id)
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        res.status(200).json(doc);
    })
.catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({error:err});
    });
});
```

[image: Post]

Comment: Requests 

GET http://localhost:3000/5e3a9663b49d7326dc19c1 and 
GET http://localhost:3000/products/5e3a9663b49d7326dc19c1 

don't work both?

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Do you get an error? or do you get  empyt response?

Comment: show the console screenshot

Comment: this is the error message i got **Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to localhost:3000/products/5e3848acbedbb83a88c30e17.** @SuleymanSah

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of postman GET request?

Comment: @SuleymanSah, I just added the screenshot

Comment: you don't have `http://`

Comment: it is same even with http://,